# IntelliJ IDEA and Maven: creating a test resource in the same package

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and my project has a default Maven structure.

I often run into the scenario where I need to create a new class or resource in the same package, but in different folder (one of `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java`, `src/test/directory`). The case where I'm editing a class in `src/main/java` and I need to create a test in `src/test/java` is covered by the *Create Test* command.
What about the other scenarios?

Often I find myself writing a unit test and I'd like to  create a test resource in the same package in test resources folder. Is there a quick way how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge (via 10 years of use) there is not a built in way to do this. It is something I've recently been desiring for creating default Spring Test Context files. Your post has promoted me to open a [Feature Request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124218) for auto-generating the spring text context. I'd recommend you either add a comment to that request, or open a separate feature request.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do at least is to copy the path of your package, and then (in the test resources dir) say new directory, and paste the path there. You then need to delete the absolute prefix, but can keep the package definition. With deep package structures, this at least helps a bit.